# Selenium webdriver link extraction

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having HTML source as

```
   <ul class="content">
    <li class="">
     <div class="profile-card">
      <div class="content">
       <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ouafae-ezzine-894b113">
         Ouafae Ezzine
        </a>
       <p class="headline">
        Organise vos evenements professionnels &amp; personnels
       </p>
       <dl class="basic">
        <dt>
         Location
        </dt>
        <dd>
         France
        </dd>
        <dt>
         Industry
        </dt>
       </dl>
       <table class="expanded hide-mobile">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <th>
           Current
          </th>
          <td>
           Responsable at Blue Med Events
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>
           Past
          </th>
          <td>
           Administrateur achats at Pfizer
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>
           Education
          </th>
          <td>
           Universite d'Evry Val d'Essonne
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>
           Summary
          </th>
          <td>
           Riche d'une experience de plus de 25 ans dans le domaine de l'organisation evenementielle, je mets mon expertise...
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
     <div class="profile-card">
      <div class="content">
       <h3>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ouafae-ezzine-892855b6">
         Ouafae Ezzine
        </a>
       </h3>
       <p class="headline">
        Gerante
       </p>
       <dl class="basic">
        <dt>
         Location
        </dt>
        <dd>
         France
        </dd>
        <dt>
         Industry
        </dt>
        <dd>
         Events Services
        </dd>
       </dl>
       <table class="expanded hide-mobile">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <th>
           Current
          </th>
          <td>
           Gerante
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

I have written a python code which will find if a given string exists in the page or not.

I am trying to write logic to extract the anchor links associated to a particular profile if the string is associated with that profile(anchor tag).

my python snnipet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('file:///nfs/users/lpediredla/Documents/linkedin/Top2profLinkedIn.html')

ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Organise vos evenements professionnels')]")

#don't know how to associate the element with the profile
#please help with the logic here.


driver.close()
```

I am struck at this point trying to associate the element with the profile bucket it sits in.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question completely, but here's code that will loop through the `ids` you find and then prints for a match for whatever string you're looking for: `for i in ids: if 'string you're looking for in i.text: print i.text`

Comment: I was just testing to see if the program able to see the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [`preceding-sibling::a`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp) to find the *anchor* tags before the *p* tags that contain the *text* `'Organise vos evenements professionnels'`:

```
"//p[contains(text(), 'Organise vos evenements professionnels')]/preceding-sibling::a"
```

Using your html:

```
In [11]: from lxml.html import fromstring

In [12]: xml = fromstring(html)

In [13]: print(xml.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Organise vos evenements professionnels')]/preceding-sibling::a"))
[<Element a at 0x7f5cae670188>]

In [14]: print(xml.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Organise vos evenements professionnels')]/preceding-sibling::a//text()"))
['\n         Ouafae Ezzine\n        ']
```

If you want to have a case insensitive match you can [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate):

```
 "//p[contains(translate(text(),'ORGANISEVOSPRLT','organisevosprlt'), 'organise vos evenements professionnels')]/preceding-sibling::a"
```

Comment: I got an empty array

Comment: @AnilPediredla, I used your source and I got  the a tag, what is the url? Also are you looking for linkedin urls?

Comment: your code works great!!

can you help me on how to check case sensitive string present in html text?

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(lower-case(text()), 'organise vos evenements professionnels')]")`

is this a valid statement?

Comment: @AnilPediredla, that would only work in xpath 2, you need to translate the characters, I will add how to change the letters to lowercase

Comment: thank you. I got the anticipated results. I have used `translate(.,'ABCD",'abcd')` to convert to lower case letter.